# How to get the container Id of the running container using docker-java?

Tags: docker, docker-java

I am running a container with name tag which allows me to identify it.In docker-java,it requires container id for most of the operations and i do not know how to get that using docker-java.Can anyone help me how to get the container Id for the running container?

For example:

> docker ps

```
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
8945dcd6195b        e7a064b1705a        "java '-Duser.time..."   4 days ago          Up 20 seconds                           runDataMock
```

> I am looking for a way by which i could get the ContainerId using the ContainerNames.

NOTE: I am aware of the below method which creates a new container and picks the id.
 dockerClient.createContainerCmd(imageName).exec().getId()

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the containers by status and by other properties using withXXX methods but there is not a WithNameFilter method in docker-java API. A workaround is to use a generic filter:

```
//get the docker client
DockerClient docker = DockerClientBuilder.getInstance(config).build();
//prepare command to retrieve the list of (running) containers 
ListContainersCmd listContainersCmd = client.listContainersCmd().withStatusFilter("running");
//and set the generic filter regarding name
listContainersCmd.getFilters().put("name", Arrays.asList("redis"));
//finally, run the command
List<Container> exec = listContainersCmd.exec();
```

and that's it!

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with a local Docker Daemon, you could use https://www.github.com/amihaiemil/docker-java-api, version 0.0.1 has just been released.

To iterate over all the running containers, all you have to do is the following:

```
final Containers containers = new LocalDocker(
    new File("/var/run/docker.sock")
).containers();
for(final Container running : containers) {
    System.out.println(running.containerId());
}
```

Study the README of the project, the motivational blogpost and the wiki, they are quite short :)

Answer (score 0):

Since this original posting date, the docker-java-api has gone through some updates. To update @amihaiemill's original answer to the updated api the code should be

```
final Docker docker = new UnixDocker( new File( "/var/run/docker.sock" ) );
final Containers containers = docker.containers();

for ( final Container running : containers ) {
    System.out.println( running.containerId() );
}

Thank you amihaiemil for your work on this project
```